# Trying to remove an object with list iterator

Tags: java, listiterator

I'm trying to remove an object from a list using the list iterator. I've gone through the other solutions on the website and none have alleviated the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

here is my code that is not executing :

```
void PatronReturn(String bookName) {
//       get to beginning
    while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        listIterator.previous();
    }
    while(listIterator.hasNext()){
        Book b = listIterator.next();
    if (listIterator.next().getBookTitle().equals(bookName)) { 
        //listIterator.next();
        //listIterator.remove();
        books.remove(b);
        //listIterator.next(); //moves to next so iterator can remove previous ?
        //books.remove(listIterator.next());; // TODO see if this is correct

    }
    }
```

Comment: why you used hasPrevious()

Comment: PSR I use has.previous() to get to the beginning of my list just to be sure i start from the beginning after an add or remove

Comment: Something is weird... You call `Book b = listIterator.next();` and then on the next line you don't use `b` but call `listIterator.next()` again. That looks strange...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Do not remove an item from a list directly. Use the `remove()` method in the iterator.
2. Your code is also flawed in that it assumes there are additional list items:

   ```
   while(listIterator.hasNext()){
       Book b = listIterator.next();
       if (listIterator.next().getBookTitle().equals(bookName)) { 
         // eek
   ```

   Here you call `next()` twice, yet you've only called `hasNext` once. Perhaps you meant:

   ```
   while(listIterator.hasNext()){
       Book b = listIterator.next();
       if (b.getBookTitle().equals(bookName)) { 
         // ...
   ```
3. Finally, you can replace:

   ```
   while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
       listIterator.previous();
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   listIterator = books.listIterator();
   ```

Comment: this is the safest way to do it. +1

Comment: well that does not work either, as you can see by my commented code, i've tried that.

Comment: @user2236278 I suspect you had other errors, related to my second point above.

Comment: The combination of both of the above snippets of code solved my problem. Java did not like setting the Iterator to the front of the list in my previous fashion, as well as, I was calling next twice as you pointed out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

instead of books.remove(b)

use

```
listIterator.remove();
```

the reason is, that the iterator gives you the next() book, if you only remove the book from books, the iterator has the "removed" book still as next book.

it did not work in your code, because you called .next() twice, once for the book b and a second time when comparing the book title, with the next book.

Answer (score 0):

instead of   `books.remove(b)`

try to use

```
   listIterator.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT remove an item from an `ArrayList` while iterating.

you can either :

- Use the remove() method of the `ListIterator` (at most once for each next())
- Use another `List` implementation, like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), wich is garanteed never to throw an `ConcurrentModificationException`, but this is probably overkill in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an item whilst iterating a list, you should use .remove()

Also remove this:

```
while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
    listIterator.previous();
}
```

This is not neccesary

Answer (score 0):

```
{   Book toBeReaplced = null; Book tempBook = null;   
void PatronReturn(String bookName)           
{//       get to beginning
while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {        listIterator.previous();
}
while(listIterator.hasNext()){
    Book tempBook = listIterator.next();
if (b.getBookTitle().equals(bookName)) { 
             toBeReaplced = tempBook;

}

listIterator.remove(bookToBeReplaced);
}
```

You can try the above code. I think it will able to solve your problem, that you have facing that java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" error. for more reference on the error please follow the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)