# Removing one object from list object using Java

Tags: java, collections

My scenario is like this.. I'm getting a list object with some duplicate objects appended. So I am trying to remove duplicate objects from list and for that, I've done in a traditional fashion. But this is not working properly so Is there any better way for this, please help

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.getPartyRec().get(0).getPersonInfo().getData().getContact().size(); i++) 
{
      if(response.getPartyRec().get(0).getPersonInfo().getData().getContact().get(i).isSetPostAddr())
       response.getPartyRec().get(0).getPersonInfo().getData().getContact().remove(i);
}
```

Can this be achieved in more efficient way?

Comment: use list iterator .. follow this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084364/5086633

Comment: @yeppe, again this is normal fashion using iterator

Comment: The first thing you should do is avoid duplication, by creating a variable to hold `response.getPartyRec().get(0).getPersonInfo().getData().getContact()` and using that in your loop.  Not only will this be a little more efficient, people who read your code will not feel like they're being tortured.

Comment: As far as what the most efficient way is: it depends on what `getContact()` is.  I'm assuming it's some kind of `List`, but I think the answer will depend on whether it's a `LinkedList` or some other kind of list, since removing an arbitrary element is O(1) for a `LinkedList` but O(n) for some other kinds.  If it's not `LinkedList`, it might be more efficient to build a new list of the elements you want to keep, instead of removing elements.  But that depends on the list size and on how many elements you're removing.  You'll have to do your own benchmarking here.

Comment: @ajb, its an internal object inside Data class which is a list object.

Comment: But what kind of list?  The answer to your question will probably differ depending on which exact list implementation it is.

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify a bit your code with a temporay object, instead of chaining 5 calls inside a for loop definition..
To remove an element while looping on a list, you may use an iterator (since java 8's removeIf is not an option):

```
Data data = response.getPartyRec().get(0).getPersonInfo().getData();

ListIterator<Contact> iter = data.getContact().listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().isSetPostAddr()){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

I think I understand that you have duplicate objects in your list, and your goal is actually to remove the duplicates. Am I right? How is isSetPostAddr() checking for duplicates ? Perhaps all you need is to convert your list into a **Set** (ie:  **HashSet**) to avoid duplicates ?

Also, you should consider adding an 's' to `getContact()` and `getPartyRec`, to show they represent a collection/list/multiple objects...: `getContacts()` and `getPartyRecs()`

Comment: We are using Java 7. Can you please check with Java 7 itself?

Comment: I mean I get two contact objects appended in that list object

Comment: I think I understand that you have duplicate objects in your list. How is isSetPostAddr() checking for duplicates ? Perhaps all you need is to convert your list into a Set to avoid duplicates ?